# importing error in python Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, html, flask, import

When trying to import functions from two files, I get errors:
I have looked at other questions like this, and I still can't get it fixed.

My code is:

```
from websiteln import initialApp
from config import Config
```

my files look like:

```
/website:
  main.py
  __init__.py
  config.py
  /websiteln
     __init__.py
```

note that the Config function is in "config.py", and initialApp is in **init**.py for the websiteln folder.

I have tried removing the "from", and it still doesn't work. Also I am using flask if that's needed.
I have tried using sys, but it still doesn't work.

```
import sys
sys.path.append("C:/Users/MYNAME/Desktop/Visual Studio Code/Python/website")
sys.path.append("C:/Users/MYNAME/Desktop/Visual Studio Code/Python/website/websiteln")
```

The specific error for each one is:

> Unable to import 'config'pylint(import-error)
> Unable to import 'websiteln'pylint(import-error)

Comment: the error says it all: What is `app`? What is the reason of the file `/website/__init__.py`?

Comment: try `from websiteln import initialApp`

Comment: @rioV8 oh sorry that was meant to say websiteln, sorry

Comment: just to confirm: it still doesn't work